# Injecting a specially-created reference into a dynamically created Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a service in Angular which I use to create components dynamically. Every time I create a component, I create a new `ActiveComponent` class which I pass the `componentRef` to, with helper functions like `close()` which interact with (close, etc) the component's instance.

Below is a pretty standard function which I use for instantiating an arbitrary Angular component. The thing I am not clear on is how to pass the new `ActiveComponent` inside the component that was just instantiated.

**Function for creating an arbitrary component**

```
  appendComponentToBody(component: any): ComponentRef<unknown> {

    // Create a component reference from the component
    const componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
      .resolveComponentFactory(component)
      .create(this.injector);

    // Create an ActiveComponent instance we can pass to the component
    // Implementation doesn't really matter but it needs to know appRef and componentRef

    const activeComponent = new ActiveComponent(this.appRef, componentRef);

    // How to pass activeComponent inside the component?

    // Attach component to the AppRef so that it's inside the Angular component tree
    this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);

    // Attach to the body
    const domElem = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
      .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

    document.body.appendChild(domElem);

    return activeComponent;
  }
}
```

**Inside the arbitrary component:**
We inject the ActiveComponent instance that was created while instantiating the component. We can use its close() method to close the component and return data from it.

```
  constructor(private activeComponent: ActiveComponent){

  }

  close(data: string){
    this.activeComponent.close(data);
  }
```

My question is: How can I inject my new ActiveComponent into the component I have just instantiated? Thanks so much!